# Session and Cookies in expressjs

Tags: node.js, express

I'm newbie to authentication, why do I need session variable.

The procedure I'm following to authenticating my users as follows.

1. Once the user is logged in, I will set a encoded cookies to user's browser.
2. For every request from the user, I will Use  app.all(" * ")  I will check whether user is logged in (and who the user is?) by comparing user cookies with my database. What's wrong with this procedure and how can I improve?

Comment: There is no need to use `app.all("*", middlewareFn)`, you can instead just do `app.use(middlewareFn)`. It essentially does the same, but it's cleaner in my opinion, since it's not a route thing, but an app thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure is, I think, absolutely correct. Session variable is nothing but the parsed session cookie got from the browser, So you are already using that session data from coockie i.e. session variable to check for authentication.

In general practice the procedure is similar to what you are saying. If you are newbie you might wanna look into libraries such as [exepress-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session) which works as session middleware function like yours and provide session data on `req.session`.

Comment: Hi Tolsee I have gone through  exepress-session middle-ware, session data still alive after closing brower window, do express-session create cookies by itself

Comment: Yeah, It create session cookie itself. You can use different options for your requirements.